# How to search date ranges using ElasticSearch and Searchkick?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using `Rails 4.1.4` with `searchkick (1.3.0)` so I can use elastic search.

I have `User` model

```
class User
  searchkick
  def search_data
    {
     name: username,
     email: email,
     created_at: created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    }
  end
end
```

`created_at` in `dd-MM-yyyy` format. How can I search for date range, let's say date from `01-01-2014` to `01-01-2015`.

I tired something like `User.search('*', where: {created_at: {gte:'01-01-2014', lte: '01-01-2015' } })` without getting the right results.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

```
class User
  searchkick
  def search_data
    {
     name: username,
     email: email,
     created_at: created_at.to_time
    }
  end
end
```

Instead of

> created_at: created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

Try

> created_at: created_at.to_time

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Searchkick, but if you use the [elasticsearch gem](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby), you can easily make a search request to ElasticSearch like

```
query = {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
           term: {
             username: "Kevin" 
           }
        },
        {
           term: {
             email: "email@gmail.com"
           } 
        },
        {
           range: {
             created_at: {
               lte: "2016-06-06",
               gte: "2016-06-06",
               format: "yyyy-MM-dd"
             }
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The search request will look like:

```
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new
client.search( 
  index: index_name,
  body: {
    query: query
  }
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your help. So for range I don't have to specify the field `created_at`?

Comment: IF I use term with searchkick I get the following error: "Unknown where operator: :range"

Comment: I just updated my query, sorry I missed the `created_at` field, you are correct. About Searchkick, I suggest you check out the src of query class https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/lib/searchkick/query.rb. I found it a little bit confusing for me haha.

Answer (score 0):

Form a proper DateTime object and your code should work
just use

```
.to_datetime
```